# Limit Number of Results being returned in a List from Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I'm using Linq/EF4.1 to pull some results from a database and would like to limit the results to the (X) most recent results.  Where X is a number set by the user.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm currently passing them back as a `List` if this will help with limiting the result set.  While I can limit this by looping until I hit X I'd just assume not pass the extra data around.

Just in case it is relevant...
C# MVC3 project running from a SQL Server database.

Comment: are you asking for linq "take(100)"?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Use the `Take` function

```
int numberOfrecords=10; // read from user
listOfItems.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).Take(numberOfrecords)
```

Assuming `listOfItems` is List of your entity objects and `CreatedDate` is a field which has the date created value (used here to do the Order by descending to get recent items).

> Take() Function returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a
>   sequence.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx

Comment: "most recent results" - that's not addressed by your answer.

Comment: @Mr.TA: Ah ! I missed that part. Updated now. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: While I didn't really need help with the most recent portion (I worded the question poorly) the take is what I needed!  Thanks!

Comment: As soon as the dumb wait to select answer timer runs out I'll select your answer... thanks again

Comment: @Shyju nope doesn't let me to, saying that the answer needs to be edited. Weird.

Comment: @Mr.TA: I made an update to the answer to include the msdn documentation about Take function. you should be able to undownvote now. and Thank You.

Comment: @Shyju Done. I provided the full answer, including the ordering, before you btw :)

Comment: @Mr.TA: The timestamp shows i was 3 seconds (or milli seconds) earlier than you.  :) ( Ofcourse i did not include the Orderby thing in my initial post).

Answer (score 41):

```
results = results.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date).Take(10);
```

The `OrderByDescending(...)` will sort items by your date/time property (or w/e logic you want to use to get most recent) and `Take(...)` will limit to first x items (first being most recent, thanks to the ordering).

**Edit:** To return some rows not starting at the first row, use `Skip()`:

```
results = results.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date).Skip(50).Take(10);
```

Comment: Is it possible to take results starting with some index? For example, one hundred results - start with index 50, take 10 results, from 50 - 60?

Comment: @FrenkyB please see the answer - I updated it to address your follow up.

Answer (score 23):

Use `Take()`, before converting to a List. This way EF can optimize the query it creates and only return the data you need.

Comment: Would you kindly elaborate more. Maybe with an example?

Comment: @W.M. Using Take first will allow EF to do the paging right in the SQL query. If you do ToList first instead, all results will be pulled back from SQL, and paging will then be done in memory.

Comment: @RedFilter is the only person that addressed my concern. I've got a set of 31000 items... it seemed wasteful to grab the entire list, just so i can pull the top 10 off the list. However, I wouldn't mind seeing an example :)