# Number of results in DbSet<TEntity>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dbcontext, dbset

I was going through some sample code about DBEntities and DbContext. Is there any limit on number of rows the DbSet pulls from the database? In the below code sample, lets say there is a `DbSet<History> history` or `DbSet<Logs> logs`, when a dbcontext is created, will `dbcontext.logs` or `dbcontext.history` has all the logs present in the database? If its so, what if the tables have millions of rows. Doesnt it hit the performance when during linq or any udpates and saving the context?

```
public virtual DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<StudentAddress> StudentAddresses { get; set; }
```

```
using (var context = await _contextFactory.CreateContext())
{
     context.History.Add(history);
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Most people use `Take` to avoid such scenarios: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883451/limit-number-of-results-being-returned-in-a-list-from-linq

Answer (score 1):

Entity framework doesn’t need to pull any rows to do an insert which is what the Add() method and SaveChanged() does. It should do what you would do in SQL to add a row to the table in question.

Comment: Add() or Select() I observed when a context is created ```context.History``` has all the rows that it has in the database which I feel is unnecessary(anticipating millions of rows). Can I limit the number of rows it pulls while a context is created?

Comment: It's a "Heisenberg effect": if you look at it, you enumerate it (expanding the IEnumerable) that's when the query is executed. Dont look at it (or with a profiler) and it will behave just fine. Use linq's Where statement to filter.

Comment: the only query being executed when a context is created (more precisely: when the modelbuilder for that context type is run for the context initializer) is the check in the migration history table in order to see if the database schema is correct. No data will be loaded from the database, unless you enumerate the IQueryables exposed or created from the DbContext's DbSet properties.

Answer (score 1):

As in your example, it doesn't "explode"

The following line basically only adds an item to an empty change tracker:

```
 context.History.Add(history);
```

If you would execute

```
context.History.ToList()
```

Then the query is executed as a "select * from History" and you will definitely hit a performance issue if it contains millions of rows.

Key point is that EF is "smart enough" to not load everything in memory as a whole set. You could attach a profiler (or enable EF logging) to see the actual queries being executed. Fiddle around a bit with it to gain some experience.

If you expand the set, for example with a debugger, then basically you don't apply any filter and will retrieve the whole set. With the misuse of navigation properties you would even be able to load your whole database in memory.

The subtitle difference is within the difference between the `IQueryable` and other `IEnumerable`-like interfaces.

While the object is still only `IQueryable` the actual query is still to be executed and can be expand with filters. As I said; once you are starting to enumerate, the actual query is executed and hence, an unfiltered dbset will return all rows in a table.

---

Also note the mentioned linq methods

.Skip

And

.Take

There are several more, like group, join, where, etc.

Comment: ^ and above comment  helps. I will try to play around the profiler to see what queries are getting executed. Thanks

Comment: Your welcome , feel free to come back if you have questions.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You have to realise that a `DbSet<Student>` does not represent your collection of `Students`, it represents the `Students` table in your database. This means that you can query for sequences of properties of `Students`.

If desired, you can query the complete sequence, but that will lead to performance problems, if not memory problems.

Therefore, if you ask for `Student` data, you have to keep in mind what you will be using of the fetched data: don't Select properties that you already know the value of, don't Select items that you don't plan to use.

An example: a database with `Schools` and `Students`, with a one-to-many relation, every `School` has zero or more `Students`, every `Student` attends exactly one `School`:

```
class School
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
     ...

     // every School has zero or more Students (one-to-many)
     public virtual ICollection<Student> Students {get; set;}
}

class Student
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
     ...

     // Every Student attends exactly one School, using foreign key:
     public int SchoolId {get; set;}
     public virtual School School {get; set;}
}
```

> In entity framework the columns of the tables are represented by non-virtual properties. The virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

**Don't do the following!**

```
public IEnumerable<School> GetSchoolByLocation(string city)
{
    return mySchoolWithItsStudents = dbContext.Schools
        .Where(school => school.City == city)
        .Include(school => school.Students)
        .ToList();
}
```

Why not? This looks like perfect code, doesn't it?

Well maybe you are fetching way more data than your caller will use:

```
var mySchoolId = GetSchoolByLocation("Oxford")
    .Where(school => schoolStreet == "Main Street")
    .Select(school => school.Id)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

What a waste, to first fetch all Oxford schools, and then keep only this one!

Furthermore: you get the school with all its Students, and all you use if the Id of the school?

> Try to return `IQueryable<...>` as long as possible, and let your caller decide what to do with the returned data.

Maybe he wants to do `ToList`, or `Count`, or `FirstOrDefault`. Maybe he only wants the `Id` and the `Name`. As long as you don't know that, don't make the decision for him, it only makes your code less reusable.

> Always use `Select` to select the properties, and select only the data you actually plan to use. Only use `Include` if you plan to update the included data.

```
var schools = dbContext.Schools.Where(school => ...)
    // Keep only the Schools that you actually plan to use:
    .Select(school => new
    {
        // only select the properties that you plan to use
        Id = school.Id,
        Name = school.Name,
        ...

        // Only the Students you plan to use:
        Students = school.Students.Where(student => ...)
            .Select(student => new
            {
                // Again, only the properties you plan to use
                Id = student.Id,
                Name = student.Name,

                // no need for the foreign key: you already know the value
                // SchoolId = student.SchoolId,
            }),
     });
```

Finally, if you want access to all `Students` to show them, but you don't want to fetch all million Students at once, consider fetching them by Page. Remember the primary key of the last item of the last fetched page, and use `.Where(item => item.Id > lastFetchedPrimaryKey).Take(pageSize) to get the next page, until there are no more pages.

This way, you might ask for 50 students, while you'll only display 25 of them, but at least you don't have all million students in memory. Fetching the next page is fairly fast, because there is already an index on primary key, and fetched items are already ordered by primary key.

Comment: I would preface "Don't do the following!" with "In (reusable) library code"

Comment: You should also not use `Include` in local code., if you would use `Include` instead of `Select`, then querying `School` 10 with its 7 thousand `Students` will transport the foreign key `SchoolId` 7000 times, while you already know that the value will be 10, the value of `School.Id`